# How to solve SciPy's handythread sample code for Python 3.x: invalid syntax error in raise?

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, python-3.x

The SciPy website has a link to a simple `parallel_map` which seems incredibly handy to use it's located [here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Multithreading)). Unfortunately, due to some differences of Python 2 vs 3, the code does not work in my environment.

The error I get is related to the `raise` syntax:

```
    from handythread import parallel_map
  File "C:\Users\Ruben\Dropbox\Doctoraat\Python\handythread.py", line 55
    raise a, b, c
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I found the documentation explaining the syntax change [here](http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html#exceptions) but I can't find a simple change to make this work. Anyone know what to fix? The relevant snippet from handythread is this:

```
for t in threadlist:
  t.join()
if exceptions:
  a, b, c = exceptions[0]
  raise a, b, c
```

Comment: If it's only an exception, you can just `raise` anything, right? a bit hackish, but your code will run. Anyway, from the documentation it seems you should do `raise a.with_traceback(c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example they get the `sys.exc_info()` tuple and store it into the `exceptions` list:

```
e = sys.exc_info()
exceptions.append(e)
```

`sys.exc_info()` returns `(type, value, traceback)`, so you can just re-raise the original exception:

```
a, b, c = exceptions[0]
raise b
```

But I would suggest to do:

```
a, b, c = exceptions[0]
raise a(b).with_traceback(c)
```

Which will preserve the complete, original, traceback and make debugging of your code much easier.

Answer (score 0):

@justhalf's suggestion is quite reasonable, but in case you want to do it right, follow the instructions in this [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3109/) (search for "Three-expression raise statements will be converted from"). Or you can run the script through `2to3` which will do it automatically.